# Find an increasing arithmetic sequence of n real numbers whose sum is equal to N

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

For example, i am looking for the sequence of 7 increasing numbers starting from 0 whose sum is 0.7 (more or less) with uniform distribution (the gap between the numbers are equal).
It seems to me there is something to do with the pyramid but I did not find what i wanted into the web.

edit: this kind of sequence is usually called arithmetic progression

Comment: This is not clear.  seven numbers sum to a fixed number, where does a distribution enter into it?

Comment: starting from 0

Comment: That doesn't help.  Can you give an example of a sequence of $7$ numbers that  sums to $.7$ but does *not* meet your criterion, and explain how it fails?

Comment: It is still unclear what you mean. Would 7x0.1 work? If not, why not?

Comment: Ok, so let's say 0.04+0.08+0.12+0.16+0.2 = 0.6 : the sequence is increasing with 0.04 interval but it is not equal to 0.7. Moreover, I computed this one by hand but I'm looking for a formula/algorithm

Comment: You want $7$ numbers *in arithmetic progression* that sum to $.7$ it sounds like.  Do you want the first number in the progression to be $0?$  Is that what "starting from $0$" in your earlier comment means?

Comment: As I said, this isn't clear at all.  Did you want the gaps to be equal?  You didn't specify that.  If we call the gap $g$ then your sequence is $0,g,2g,3g,4g,5g,6g$ which sums to $g\times (1+2+3+4+5+6)=21g$.  If you want that to be $.7$ we solve as $g=\frac {.7}{21}=.0\overline 3$.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: If what saulsplatz writes is true, take any $d$ and the seven values are $0.1-3d, 0.1-2d, 0.1-d, 0.1, 0.1+d, 0.1+2d, 0.1+3d$. This is an arithmetic progression of size 7 with the desired result. Since (I think) you want the first number to be zero, choose $d=\frac{0.1}3=0.03333\ldots$ and you get $0 + 0.0.03333\ldots + 0.06666\ldots + 0.1 + 0.13333\ldots + 0.16666\ldots + 0.2 = 0.7$

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  I note that your "example" only has five terms.  Perhaps you meant to add $0$ without stating it, but even so that would be six terms not seven.

Comment: Sorry, i put indeed only 5 terms: i did it wrong by hand that is why i need a algorithm. When i spoke about uniformly distributed I was trying to say that the gap needed to be equal. And yes it seems that you resolved my problem: the arithmetic progression was the keyword I missed in my research.

Comment: Ok.  So if you want length $n$ just repeat the calculation I gave.  You should get $.7=g_n\times (1+\cdots +(n-1))=g_n\times \frac {n(n-1)}2\implies g_n=\frac {1.4}{n(n-1)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

Given $n\in \mathbb N$ the OP is asking for a value $g_n$ such that the series $$0+g_n+2g_n+\cdots +(n-1)g_n=.7$$

We remark that this can be solved as $$.7=g_n\times (1+2+\cdots +(n-1))=g_n\times \frac {n(n-1)}2\implies \boxed {g_n=\frac {1.4}{n(n-1)}}$$

For instance, with $n=7$ we get $g_7=\frac 1{30}$.

Of course, there is nothing special about the value $.7$